# Iteration for time series data, using purrr

Tags: r, time-series, purrr

I have a bunch of time series data stacked on top of one another in a data frame; one series for each region in a country. I'd like to apply the `seas()` function (from the `seasonal` package) to each series, iteratively, to make the series seasonally adjusted. To do this, I first have to convert the series to a `ts` class. I'm struggling to do all this using `purrr`.

Here's a minimum worked example:

```
library(seasonal)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(region = rep(1:10, each = 20),
             quarter = rep(1:20, 10),
             var = sample(5:200, 200, replace = T))
```

For each region (indexed by a number) I'd like to perform the following operations. Here's the first region as an example:

```
tem1 <- df %>% filter(region==1)
tem2 <- ts(data = tem1$var, frequency = 4, start=c(1990,1)) 
tem3 <- seas(tem2)
tem4 <- as.data.frame(tem3$data)
```

I'd then like to stack the output (ie. the multiple tem4 data frames, one for each region), along with the region and quarter identifiers.

So, the start of the output for region 1 would be this:

```
  final seasonaladj trend irregular region quarter
1    27          27 96.95 -67.97279      1       1
2   126         126 96.95  27.87381      1       2
3   124         124 96.95  27.10823      1       3
4   127         127 96.95  30.55075      1       4
5   173         173 96.95  75.01355      1       5
6   130         130 96.95  32.10672      1       6
```

The data for region 2 would be below this etc.

I started with the following but without luck so far. Basically, I'm struggling to get the time series into the tibble:

```
seas.adjusted <- df %>%
group_by(region) %>% 
mutate(data.ts = map(.x = data$var, 
                     .f = as.ts, 
                     start = 1990,
                     freq = 4))
```

Comment: thanks for including your code so far.  Could you also include the desired dataframe/output?  Truncate it if necessary; just enough to demonstrate your intentions.

Comment: edits in original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about the seasonal adjustment part, so there may be things I missed, but I can help with moving your calculations into a `map`-friendly function.

After grouping by region, you can nest the data so there's a nested data frame for each region. Then you can run essentially the same code as you had, but inside a function in `map`. Unnesting the resulting column gives you a long-shaped data frame of adjustments.

Like I said, I don't have the expertise to know whether those last two columns having `NA`s is expected or not.

**Edit**: Based on @wibeasley's question about retaining the `quarter` column, I'm adding a `mutate` that adds a column of the quarters listed in the nested data frame.

```r
library(seasonal)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(region = rep(1:10, each = 20),
                 quarter = rep(1:20, 10),
                 var = sample(5:200, 200, replace = T))

df %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data.ts = map(data, function(x) {
    tem2 <- ts(x$var, frequency = 4, start = c(1990, 1))
    tem3 <- seas(tem2)
    as.data.frame(tem3$data) %>%
      mutate(quarter = x$quarter)
  })) %>%
  unnest(data.ts)
#> # A tibble: 200 x 8
#>    region final seasonaladj trend irregular quarter seasonal adjustfac
#>     <int> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1      1    27          27  97.0    -68.0        1       NA        NA
#>  2      1   126         126  97.0     27.9        2       NA        NA
#>  3      1   124         124  97.0     27.1        3       NA        NA
#>  4      1   127         127  97.0     30.6        4       NA        NA
#>  5      1   173         173  97.0     75.0        5       NA        NA
#>  6      1   130         130  97.0     32.1        6       NA        NA
#>  7      1     6           6  97.0    -89.0        7       NA        NA
#>  8      1    50          50  97.0    -46.5        8       NA        NA
#>  9      1   135         135  97.0     36.7        9       NA        NA
#> 10      1   105         105  97.0      8.81      10       NA        NA
#> # ... with 190 more rows
```

I also gave a bit more thought to doing this without nesting, and instead tried doing it with a `split`. Passing that list of data frames into `imap_dfr` let me take each split piece of the data frame and its name (in this case, the value of `region`), then return everything `rbind`ed back together into one data frame. I sometimes shy away from nested data just because I have trouble seeing what's going on, so this is an alternative that is maybe more transparent.

```r
df %>%
  split(.$region) %>%
  imap_dfr(function(x, reg) {
    tem2 <- ts(x$var, frequency = 4, start = c(1990, 1))
    tem3 <- seas(tem2)
    as.data.frame(tem3$data) %>%
      mutate(region = reg, quarter = x$quarter)
  }) %>%
  select(region, quarter, everything()) %>%
  head()
#>   region quarter final seasonaladj trend irregular seasonal adjustfac
#> 1      1       1    27          27 96.95 -67.97274       NA        NA
#> 2      1       2   126         126 96.95  27.87378       NA        NA
#> 3      1       3   124         124 96.95  27.10823       NA        NA
#> 4      1       4   127         127 96.95  30.55077       NA        NA
#> 5      1       5   173         173 96.95  75.01353       NA        NA
#> 6      1       6   130         130 96.95  32.10669       NA        NA
```

Created on 2018-08-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: @camile, I love your use of `nest()`.  Do you have ideas how to include a `quarter` column?  Experimenting on my own, I used `nest()` with a function similar to my `f()` below.  But it's still using my hack of reintroducing `quarter`.

Comment: @wibeasley Good question, I'm revisiting that now

Answer (score 1):

I put all the action inside of `f()`, and then called it with [`purrr::map_df()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).  The re-inclusion of `quarter` is a hack.

```
f <- function( .region ) {
  d <- df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(region == .region)
  y <- d %>% 
    dplyr::pull(var) %>% 
    ts(frequency = 4, start=c(1990,1)) %>% 
    seas() 

  y$data %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    # dplyr::select(-seasonal, -adjustfac) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
      quarter  = d$quarter
    )
}

purrr::map_df(1:10, f, .id = "region")
```

results:

```
    region     final seasonaladj     trend     irregular quarter     seasonal   adjustfac
1        1  27.00000    27.00000  96.95000 -6.797279e+01       1           NA          NA
2        1 126.00000   126.00000  96.95000  2.787381e+01       2           NA          NA
3        1 124.00000   124.00000  96.95000  2.710823e+01       3           NA          NA
4        1 127.00000   127.00000  96.95000  3.055075e+01       4           NA          NA
5        1 173.00000   173.00000  96.95000  7.501355e+01       5           NA          NA
6        1 130.00000   130.00000  96.95000  3.210672e+01       6           NA          NA
7        1   6.00000     6.00000  96.95000 -8.899356e+01       7           NA          NA
8        1  50.00000    50.00000  96.95000 -4.647254e+01       8           NA          NA
9        1 135.00000   135.00000  96.95000  3.671077e+01       9           NA          NA
10       1 105.00000   105.00000  96.95000  8.806955e+00      10           NA          NA
...
96       5  55.01724    55.01724  60.25848  9.130207e-01      16    1.9084928   1.9084928
97       5  60.21549    60.21549  59.43828  1.013076e+00      17    1.0462424   1.0462424
98       5  58.30626    58.30626  58.87065  9.904130e-01      18    0.1715082   0.1715082
99       5  61.68175    61.68175  58.07827  1.062045e+00      19    1.0537962   1.0537962
100      5  59.30138    59.30138  56.70798  1.045733e+00      20    2.5294523   2.5294523
...
```